# How can I check if a taxonomy has more than one item?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm templating a single.php and I want to display something like 'Destination: Paris' or 'Destinations: Paris, London'. So I'd like to check if the taxonomy 'Destination' has more than one item in order to output 'Destination' if tax has only one item and 'Destinations' if tax has more than one item. Thanks for any help you guys might provide!

Comment: You mean “if current post has more than one term in given taxonomy”, right?

Comment: Yes, Krzysiek. That's precisely what I mean.

Comment: ok, So my answer should be helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to check if current post has more than one term in given taxonomy (it's not very clear in your question and this version makes much more sense for me...), then function [`get_the_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) will come handy:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy );
echo ( count($terms) > 1 ) ? 'Destinations' : 'Destination';
```

Comment: This code works fine for me and I understand it. I'll use it. Thank you very much, hasta luego.

Comment: @Emmanuel No problem. Just remember to mark answer as correct one if it was helpful ;)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your answer is useful and correct, but I can't mark it because 'This action requires 15 reputation.' and I have no reputation (I'm blushing).

Comment: @Emmanuel wow, I forgot how it was to be a new member :) No problem. You can always upvote it, I guess... nevertheless, I’m glad it helped you :)